# canonical issue?

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I have an video hosting site, there all videos are displaying like word press posts  with pagination, and there are some categories called hollywood, bollyood..etc, and there are video Genres also, ultimately all videos are displayed on home page with pagination, In this case where should i & how should i use rel = canonical tag

## Url Structure:

> example.com
>
> > all videos means hollyood , bollywood, love ...all genres ...ect
>
> example.com/hollywood/
>
> > only hollywood videos
>
> example.com/hollywood/genres/love
>
> > only love songs videos

Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

You don't need canonical URLs for this. This isn't duplicate content. Duplicate content only is an issue when two different URLs pull up the exact same content (sometimes with minor changes like a list being in a different order).

Answer (score 0):

Q : First you have understand "what is it"?

A : A canonical issue arises when 301 redirects are not properly in place. This means that your website can be accessed by search engines from several different URLs. This means that search engines can then potentially index your site under different URLs, meaning that it will look like a site of duplicated content.

Q : Brother you have understand second why we use for ?

A : Simple we just want to show to google that url should crawl on SERP.

Q : How to use it ?

A : Use in header < link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />